# Navigate in amp-script

Tags: amp-html, ampscript, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have an input select that sets a state "selectedStateId", an amp-autocomplete that sets "selectedCity", and finally an input text as a search bar that sets "inputTerms".

With these I make a URL like: https://example.com/find?city_id=selectedCity&terms=inputTerms

The thing is, I needed some validations to occur in cascade so I created an amp-script

```html
<amp-script script="searchValidationScript" data-ampdevmode target="amp-script">
  <button type='button' class="button button-primary" id="header-search-button">
      <amp-img
      alt="magnifying-glass"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/icons/magnifying-glass.svg') }}"
      height="20"
      width="21"
      ></amp-img>
  </button>
</amp-script>
<script id="searchValidationScript" type='text/plain' target="amp-script">
    const searchBtn = document.getElementById('header-search-button');
    const btnSend = document.getElementById('btn-send');
    const lightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox-input-states');

    async function validateAndRedirect() {
        const currentCityId = await AMP.getState('currentCityId');
        const currentStateId = await AMP.getState('currentStateId');
        const inputTerms = await AMP.getState('inputTerms');

        if ( !inputTerms || inputTerms?.length < 2 ) return

        if ( !currentCityId || !currentStateId ) return AMP.setState({showLightbox: true})

        const urlX = `/{{ current_country.permalink }}/find?city_id=${currentCityId}&terms=${inputTerms}`
        AMP.setState({url: urlX})
    }

    searchBtn.addEventListener('click', validateAndRedirect);
</script>
```

When I click on the search button I want to redirect to the url that I've created.

I've tried in the amp-script to do an AMP.navigateTo(url=myUrl), also with an <a [href]='myUrl' hidden> and then in the amp-script aTag.click(), the same with a form tag and many examples more but I couldn't get anything to work.

Which could be a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you set your meta value, e.g. `<meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-" />`

Comment: Yes, I've set that meta tag

Comment: what do you see in the dev console? for example, do you fetch the src target? and where do you set `amp-state` values?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

As i see, `AMP.navigateTo` works only for user gestures and from amphtml:

- `<select on="change:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://')">`
- `<button on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://')">`
- `<form action-xhr="" on="submit-success: AMP.navigateTo(url='https://')"`

And you can't submit/click/etc this elements from script.

[image]